# Java LinkedList issues - how to remove items that meet certain qualifications

Tags: java, object, linked-list

I have a question,

Here is what I need to do -

I have `BankItem`s that are associated with numbers. I fill the list but when an objects enters that is $100 more than the lowest dollar value currently in the list, I want to delete the object that has the low value.

First - I create the list

```
    List<BankItem> listOfBankItems = new LinkedList<BankItem>();
```

Later in the program I create a new BankItem object and it to the list

```
listOfBankItems.add(createdItem);
```

and after adding each item I want to check to see if the new item is $100 more than any object already in the list so I run something like this

```
   for (int i = 0; i < listOfBankItems.size(); i++) {
    int oldValue =listOfBankItems.get(i).getAmount();
    int  newValue = createdItem.getAmount();
    int calculatedDif = newValue - oldValue;


    if (calculatedDif > 100) {
       listOfBankItems.remove(i); 
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this isn't working. I don't know what it up. Maybe I shouldn't use a `LinkedList`? Maybe my logic is way off-base. Please help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You can use some sorted data-structure, like TreeMap, or implement Heap or use Priority Queue.

Comment: The sorting isn't required to implement what you want, but @Bhushan is right - that will make the algorithm a lot faster if you use early breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your most significant issue probably relates to concurrent modification.  For example, if element #49 is the one to be removed, once you remove it, the next element will now be #49, but you will be checking for #50 (as `i` was still incremented) - so you're probably missing elements from your check.

There are a few ways to handle this.  You could remove the `i++` from your `for` loop (leaving only the trailing semi-colon), then do this:

```
if (calculatedDif > 100) {
   listOfBankItems.remove(i); 
} else {
   i++;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) and its `remove()` method, which would handle this for you automatically.

You can also improve the performance of this by not obtaining `newValue` and recalculating `calculatedDif` on every step of the loop.  Declare these 2 lines above the `for` loop.

Comment: +1 to Ernest's answer, for which he provided a concrete example of what I mentioned as my alternative - which I would recommend.  (Thank him for doing your homework for you!  :-)

Comment: I think your answer is actually better: you've got two alternatives for fixing it, plus a hint for performance improvement (which is also sort of a style thing, it's clearer what the intent is if those two lines are above the loop.)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that the index of all items after the removed one will change after you remove that element; therefore you'll basically skip the next element after you remove one.

Use an iterator:

```
for (Iterator<BankItem> itr = listOfBankItems.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
    BankItem item = itr.next();
    int oldValue = item.getAmount();
    int newValue = createdItem.getAmount();
    int calculatedDif = newValue - oldValue;
    if (calculatedDif > 100) {
       itr.remove(); 
    }
}
```